# Appending % sign in output of prop.table

Tags: r, sweave

I'm trying to append % sign in the output of `prop.table` to use in `Sweave`. My attempted code is below:

```
m <- matrix(1:4,2)
dimnames(m) <- list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"))
prop.table(m,1)*100

         C        D
A 25.00000 75.00000
B 33.33333 66.66667


paste(round(prop.table(m,1)*100, 3), "%", sep = "")
[1] "25%"     "33.333%" "75%"     "66.667%"


paste(sprintf("%.1f", prop.table(m,1)*100), "%", sep = "")
[1] "25.0%" "33.3%" "75.0%" "66.7%"
```

Using `paste` will change the class from matrix to character. I'd highly appreciate if someone guide me the right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most functions designed to work with vectors also accept matrices but return a vector instead of a matrix: `paste`, `sprintf`, etc.
You can use `apply`, that will return a matrix.

```
apply( 
  prop.table(m,1)*100, 
  2, 
  function(u) sprintf( "%.1f%%", u ) 
)
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Vincent. This what I was looking for. Do you any function which will allow to append cell frequencies as well as cell percentages in the same cell table to be for Sweave? Anyhow thanks for your useful answer.

Comment: You could concatenate the two matrices with `mapply`, and explicitely convert the resulting vector into a matrix: `m1 <- apply(m, 2, as.character);
m2 <- apply(prop.table(m,1)*100, 2, function(u) sprintf("%.1f%%", u));
m3 <- mapply(paste, m1, " (", m2, ")", sep="");
m3 <- matrix(m3, nr=nrow(m)); m3`. However, to preserve the alignment in the table, I would probably use a loop to explicitely write the LaTeX code for the table.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution could be replacing content of matrix:

```
m2 <- m
m2[] <- sprintf("%.1f%%",round(prop.table(m,1)*100, 3))
m2
#   C       D      
# A "25.0%" "75.0%"
# B "33.3%" "66.7%"
```

Comment: Nice solution. Can get the same solution by this `m2[] <- sprintf("%.1f%%",prop.table(m,1)*100)` too. Thanks

Comment: Or even `replace(m, TRUE, sprintf("%.1f%%",prop.table(m,1)*100))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I forgot about this function. And `replace(m, , sprintf("%.1f%%",prop.table(m,1)*100))` works too.

Answer (score 5):

There's a package called `janitor` that takes care of the `prop.table()` "format-as-percentage" problem. Here's a link to the package: https://github.com/sfirke/janitor

Here's a usage example from the github page.

```
roster %>%
  tabyl(employee_status, full_time) %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
  adorn_ns() %>%
  adorn_title("combined")
#>  employee_status/full_time         No        Yes
#>             Administration   0.0% (0) 100.0% (1)
#>                      Coach 100.0% (2)   0.0% (0)
#>                    Teacher  33.3% (3)  66.7% (6)
#>                      Total  41.7% (5)  58.3% (7)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of the answer from @VincentZoonekynd that adds margins (totals for rows/columns) and removes the double quotes:

```
library(magrittr)

m %>%
  prop.table %>%
  addmargins %>%
  apply(MARGIN=2, FUN=scales::percent, accuracy=0.1) %>%
  noquote

#>     C     D     Sum   
#> A   10.0% 30.0% 40.0% 
#> B   20.0% 40.0% 60.0% 
#> Sum 30.0% 70.0% 100.0%
```